# Using list manager in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Am building an application with oracle apex 5 where i want the user to chose multiple parameters and returning an interactive report based on the parameters selected by the user.

One of the parameters is a list manager item where the user select multiple values to be passed to an SQL query.
my problem is how to pass those values to the sql query, the item type is list manager and the name is P2_OPTIONS how do i pass the parameters to the SQL query generating the report.

Answer (score 0):

Selected values storing in P2_OPTIONS divided by colon, for example 2:7:17.

So, you can insert this string into your query, preliminary replacing colon to comma and get expression like

...
*and parameter0 in (2,7,17)*
...

OR

you can parse this string into apex collection and join this collection in you query

...*and apex_collections.collection_name = 'P2_OPTIONS_PARSED' 
and parameter0 = apex_collections.c001* 
...